# Can I freeze the angle of a shape?

Tags: pymunk

Like Unitys transfrom,If you freeze the rotate,object will never rotate in its x axis.

Dose pymunk have this function?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the moment of the Body to infinity.
At creation:
`mybody = pymunk.Body(mass, pymunk.inf)` 
or later:
 `mybody.moment = pymunk.inf`

See http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.inf and [http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.Body.**init**](http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.Body.__init__)